# Validate token sent from azure static web app to byo function

Tags: azure, single-page-application

I want my function app to be able to validate the token sent from SWA service itself if in the authentication
settings of the function app, the identity provider (azure static web apps (linked)) established on linking is set
to allow unauthenticated requests. The reason I want to do this is to save money and host the function on
an existing function app that is vnet integrated and cannot upset existing functions by requiring authentication.
The token that is returned from SWA can be easily validated but I don't know how to find the kid and ergo the signing certificate, given that
the app id in the portal has the form random-name.azurestaticapps.net

Does anyone know if this is possible before I go down the spa MSAL route and ignore SWA inbuilt authentication?

The token received
in my function app after the ramble above looks like this.

```
{
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kid": "oOxnukAHRuDzFwkfhXgsLP7ONGI",
    "typ": "JWT"
}
{
    "prn": "<base 64 chunk removed>",
    "sub": "<guid removed>",
    "iss": "https://random-name.azurestaticapps.net/.auth",
    "aud": "https://mylinkedfunction.azurewebsites.net",
    "nbf": 1629974700,
    "exp": 1629975000,
    "iat": 1629974700
}
```

I've looked here for the kid

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/V2.0/keys
https://login.microsoftonline.com/Mytenant/discovery/keys
https://login.microsoftonline.com/Mytenant/discovery/V2.0/keys
```

Not sure where else to look.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you eventually find a solution?